# FCM getToken() returns null

Tags: ionic3

I built ionic3 app and using FCM to send push notification , I try to get the token when app opened , I have two android emulators one of them return the token and the other return null !!!
how can I fix this ?

Comment: are you calling the token in the device ready function?